# What is the meaning of "D" near with players name?

Tags: wsop

I have been watching these [WSOP 2012 videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ai9AvT-oK5c&feature=player_detailpage#t=1768s). Sometimes there is a `D` letter near the player's name. What does that mean? Look at the right side of the Robbin's name.

[image]

Comment: democrat... ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means his position is on the dealer button (hence the 'D'), which is the best position to have in Hold 'Em and Omaha games. This position is to the right of the small blind and is last to act on all postflop streets.

Comment: It's to the right of the small blind, not the left :) . +1 though :)