# What is the D on table and the terms defining players?

Tags: texas-hold-em, online

Please tell me what is The coin like thing on table [playing online]with written D on it?It keeps on circulating, after every pot it is passed beside next player.

[image]

Also tell me if the terms like Cowboy ,Pro ,Shark ,Big-Dog used in real poker too to resemble the experience of player ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coin-like thing on the table is a marker used to indicate the player who is the dealer, and this marker is called the *button* or *dealer button*. The button circulates around the table in a clock-wise direction one player at a time after each completed game. Now in casino games, the player holding the button does not actually act as the dealer and deals the cards to each other players, instead an employee from the *house* does it. Since the player with this position is always the last to act thus giving the player an advantage, hence the rotating button is there to prevent cheating so that every player gets to take turns serving as dealer.

As for the terms you mentioned given to the players:

- *Cowboys* is pocket kings(KK), a reference to a starting hand e.g. *I got the cowboys*
- *Pro* should be self-explanatory
- *Shark* describes a player who's very good/expert
- *Big dog* means a big [underdog](http://pokerterms.com/underdog.html) to win the pot

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

the names you mentioned are just names piked by the players (they have no meaning in "pokerish").

the D represents the dealer. please refer to [this question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/980/what-is-the-meaning-of-d-near-with-players-name/981#981).

Comment: Hey ! the names are not picked by players. It is given itself to players and changed as XP increases.

Comment: Ok, so the site gives it to them. it still have nothing with poker.

Answer (score 0):

The "D" i short for "dealer button" and its used to keep track of where the big blind and small blind is to be placed. In your case the small blind 1$ and the big blind is 2$ and these are forced bets.

The terms you asking about is just names. But you have terms in poker like

Shark = Very good player
Donk = Super bad player
Fish = Super bad player